# How to sort a Python list descending based on item count, but return a list with sorted items only, and not a count also?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am generating some large lists in python, and I need to figure out the absolute fastest way to return a sort list from something like this:

```
myList = ['a','b','c','a','c','a']
```

and return a list of it in descending order, based on the count of the items, so it looks like this.

```
sortedList = ['a','c','b']
```

I have been using Counter().most_common(), but this returns a tuple in descending order with the item, and the number of times in appears in the list.  I really just need a tuple or list in descending order based off count, with just the items, and not the count amounts. Any ideas?

Edit:
So would doing something like this be faster?

```
myList = ['a','b','c','a','c','a']
count = Counter(myList).most_common()
res = [k for k,v in count]
```

Comment: Just list-comp over the `most_common` to only select the key?

Comment: `sorted(counter_obj, key=counter_obj.__getitem__, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

myList = ['a','b','c','a','c','a']
res = [k for k,v in Counter(myList).most_common()]
# ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Comment: Not the fastest way though, no need to introduce a Python for-loop.

Comment: @200OK Since `.most_common()` is sorting anyway... no need to pre-generate a Counter, then sort using its values using a look up either...

Comment: @200OK a comprehension loops at C speed so I'm not sure what your point is.  The fact that comprehension grammar includes the word "for" doesn't means it performs like an actual `for` loop.

Comment: On a test I just ran comparing 1M choices of 'a','b','c', I got exactly 139 ms for each, so whatever minor performance differences there are probably wash out at large size anyway.

Comment: @JonClements I thought OP wanted to use the `Counter` later as well, if that's not the case then this is fastest solution I guess.

Comment: @200OK wasn't my interpretation, but in that case - the current code can stay as put, just assign the `Counter` outside the list-comp

Comment: I just wanted to get a list returned descending based off count, but without the actual count amounts. If is not crucial to use Counter, just seemed like the only way to do that before I posted here.

Comment: @mg1986 you have to pre-calc the frequency before hand regardless in able to order it (better a one-time pass and count, then count for each time for each key)... easiest to do that using a `Counter` than take off the info you don't need by unpacking the results and just retaining the key

Comment: @JonClements In that case it'd be better to use `sorted` directly because `.most_common()` internally calls `sorted()` only(when `n` is not passed). So, we can prevent the list comprehension loop that way. But yes, this would matter only if the `Counter` contains very large number of keys.

Comment: @200OK How long we keeping this name for? :p

Comment: @JonClements Name changed. :D